Replacing the sequence in Chowla's conjecture and positiveness of the entropy
For any fixed integer $m>0$ and not-all-even $(a_1,\ldots,a_m)\in\mathbb N^m$, one version of Chowla's conjecture states that
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{x}\sum_{n\leq x}\mu(n+1)^{a_1}\cdots\mu(n+m)^{a_m}=0,
$$
where $\mu$ is the Möbius function.
I learnt without knowing any reference that $\mu(n)$ as a sequence has positive entropy (Please feel free to share the reference for this).
I wonder if we replace $\mu(n)$ by any real bounded sequence $c_n$ or even assume that $c_n\in \{-1,0,1\}$, and assume for some/all $m$ and not-all-even $(a_1,\ldots,a_m)\in\mathbb N^m$,
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{x}\sum_{n\leq x}c_{n+1}^{a_1}\cdots c_{n+m}^{a_m}=0,
$$
is true, then could we conclude any information on the entropy of the sequence $c_n$? Or least least prove that $c_n$ has positive entropy?
For the definition of the entropy of a sequence, see Terrence Tao's blog here.

A proof that $\mu(n)$ has positive entropy is in these lectures by Sarnak (https://publications.ias.edu/sites/default/files/MobiusFunctionsLectures%282%29.pdf) - see Theorem 10.

@ThomasBloom Thanks! This is only for lecture 1. Do you know where I can find lecture 2 and lecture 3?

The proof this sequence has positive entropy relies on the construction (and computation of entropy) of the square free factor, which is composed of digits which are either $0$ or $1$, so the last assumption is clearly not needed. It is not currently known if one gets more entropy by moving from the square free factor to the whole subshift over mobius. This idea was vastly generalized by Weiss et al. that showed uniqueness of MME in such B free system and classified some of the measures. By some version of the variational principle, it shows any such system have positive topological entropy.
